# Authorship;first,second,co

Tags: publications, authorship

I am finishing my first paper. I am unaware of how I should treat a certain situation, and have come  here for advice.

The paper is about 30 pages long. I have written 26 of those pages. On the pages I wrote, the other person helped with how thoughts are to be expressed, but all the theorems and proofs were done by me. The ideas of the paper are mine, and their execution.

How is the authorship to be divided in such an example? Should I be the first author or the corresponding author? Both? Should he be the second author, or the co-author?

I read this answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2467/what-does-first-authorship-really-mean?rq=1), saying in math and computer science all authors are considered to have contributed equally. How should the ranking be notated than?

EDIT:

Question in partially answered in the linking answer (duplicate), at the comments bellow.

Comment: First author, second author, corresponding author: They're all authors. 
Whenever there is more than one author, all authors are co-authors in relation to each other. Corresponding author is one author and can be assigned to any authorial position. The LaTeX issue is a minor technical issue that has no relationship with the fundamental question of (a) who should be corresponding author? (b) What should the order of authorship be? I feel like you may want to edit your question to focus probably on the basic questions of author order and who goes corresponding author.

Comment: I have edited the title and the body. Thank you for your comment. Might you offer an insight on ordering? I think you cleared up the corresponding author issue already.

Comment: I took out LaTex tag because it is no longer relevant.

Comment: If you mean that you are in either math or CS (by the last sentence), then the authors should be listed alphabetically. Who should be corresponding author is just deciding who wishes to deal with the journal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, I am. How is first, second authorship notated than? Or is it the case, that is is not.

Comment: The order of authors is the order in which they are listed on the publication (reading from left to right as always). In math and theoretical CS, nobody cares which place in the order you are (since as I said, it is alphabetical rather than by contribution).

Comment: Thank you, your comments, and the possible duplicate answered my question.

Comment: Please specify your field in your question. The authorship is very much field dependent.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Simply, you should be the first author.</strike>

A corresponding author will be responsible for replying to the queries come from the research community and help them to a better understanding as well as gain more citations. There are other things can you find them in the link below.

Finally, If the other author can do this task, make him the corresponding author and you can help him when needs.

This post talk about [The difference between Corresponding author and First author.](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Difference_between_Corresponding_author_and_First_author_and_what_are_all_their_responsibilities)

Comment: Simply, this might be incorrect depending on the field of the OP.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft can you provide an example?

Comment: This was covered in the comments to the question. The OP is in a subject where authors are listed alphabetically, so they should only be first author if their name comes first alphabetically.